# linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' for architecture i386

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcode5

I recently switched my development MacBook from a classic MacBook (32 bit) to a MacBook Air (64 bit). I am trying to open a project that was made on my old MacBook (32 bit) running XCode 4.

The project is a PhoneGap application made in PhoneGap 1.7.0.

**My new MacBook Air (64 bit) is running XCode 5.**

I imported my developer profiles from my old MacBook to my new MacBook Air. But when I try to run it, I get the following error message.

[image]

[image]

I have tried changing the my architecture in the build settings to armv7 but still no luck :(

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to re-build that dylib to target the iOS device AND simulator.

Comment: Find the original project that built the dylib and create an iOS target for it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK so as it turns out, XCode 5 changes the default architecture to armv7 when my application does not support armv7. I am running Cordova 1.7.0 and that version does not have support for armv7 architecture.

## Fix architecture issue:

1. Removed **ALL** architectures from `Build Settings` -->
   `Valid Architecture`
2. Added `armv6` to `Build Settings` --> `Valid Architecture`
   [image]

## Fix `libSystem.B.dylib` issue:

3. Removed `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` from `Build Settings` --> `Linking` --> `Other Linker Flags`
4. Also removed `-weak_library` from `Build Settings` --> `Linking` --> `Other Linker Flags`
   [image]

Comment: in my case, i am trying to run the project made in xcode 4.5 into xcode 5.0. So this error occurs in every project. so i removed all the linker flags from 'other Linker Flags'  and it works.

Comment: Thanks so much mate for this....exactly my problem... and excatly the solution i needed :)

Comment: After 2 weeks of searching for a solution, this was it!

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 5 asks you to build your libraries for the simulator (1) and for iOS (2). You can then merge (3) these into a fat binary which you then link to your main project. I use the same flags as Xcode is using to build your main project (as seen in your screendump).

Expressed in common gnu toolchain variables I do:

**1. Building a library for the simulator**

```
CC=clang
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"
CFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0"
```

**2. Building a library for iOS**

```
CC=clang
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"
CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=7.0"
```

**3. Merging to a fat binary**

Choose either of `.a` or `.dylib` depending on what you use:

```
lipo -create "your armv7 lib".a     "your simulator lib".a     -output "your lib".a
lipo -create "your armv7 lib".dylib "your simulator lib".dylib -output "your lib".dylib
```

Comment: Where would I type these?  Is it in terminal?  Also, for step 3, can I call those libs whatever I want?  What would replace the placeholder text?