# While building iOS application with Xcode 5 in simulator, i got following error

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, ios-simulator

The error ld: in

```
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib',
```

missing required architecture i386 in file

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (2 slices) for architecture i386
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

i think you can find your answer here

[linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105131/linking-against-dylib-built-for-macosx-file-usr-lib-libsystem-b-dylib-for-arc)

may it useful for you

Comment: I already tried the link you have given, but that points to different issue, and hence not worked for me.