# building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib' for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, macports

I get the above error message when trying to built a iOS7 project, I just cloned off BitBucket (sorry, it's private, thus can't link to it).

First off, I have tried all the solutions mentioned in [linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib' for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105131/linking-against-dylib-built-for-macosx-file-usr-lib-libsystem-b-dylib-for-arc), [Build Error - missing required architecture i386 in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456185/build-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file), [Building for MacOSX, but linking against dylib built for iOS Simulator file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682267/cmake-ld-building-for-macosx-but-linking-against-dylib-built-for-ios-simulator), and several more.

My system:

- Mac OS X Mavericks; 10.9.3
- XCode 5.1.1

Summary of what I've already tried:

- reinstall XCode
- reinstall Command Line Tools
- remove entires in `framework search path`
- remove several entries in `Other Linker Flags`

The error says its linking against dylib in `/opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`, which might indicate that it has something to do with my `MacPorts` installs, since only MacPort should install programs in `/opt/local/`, as far as I know.

Any ideas what I could've missed?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is more likely defaulting to OSX PATH environment variables to find that missing sqlite library.

Make sure to link it from your project in Xcode, pointing to iOS frameworks.