# Trouble compiling libnet 1.1.7 for iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming, xcode5, libnet

I'm trying to use libnet 1.1.7 in iOS project and i'm getting some errors:

```
Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/net_tools-gnkjrfjgtxkpesepyzzpunpfdwkx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/net_tools.app/net_tools normal i386
    cd /Users/admin/Desktop/net_tools
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Разработка/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Разработка/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Разработка/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Разработка/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/net_tools-gnkjrfjgtxkpesepyzzpunpfdwkx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/net_tools-gnkjrfjgtxkpesepyzzpunpfdwkx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/net_tools-gnkjrfjgtxkpesepyzzpunpfdwkx/Build/Intermediates/net_tools.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/net_tools.build/Objects-normal/i386/net_tools.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lnet -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/net_tools-gnkjrfjgtxkpesepyzzpunpfdwkx/Build/Intermediates/net_tools.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/net_tools.build/Objects-normal/i386/net_tools_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/net_tools-gnkjrfjgtxkpesepyzzpunpfdwkx/Build/Products/Debug-

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libnet.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libnet.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_libnet_addr2name4", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_libnet_addr2name6_r", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_libnet_destroy", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_libnet_init", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_libnet_name2addr4", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_libnet_name2addr6", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my simple code in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <libnet.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    libnet_t *lnet;
    char errbuf[LIBNET_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    u_int32_t addr;
    struct libnet_in6_addr addr6;
    char ipv6addr[64];
    char addr_str[] = "www.google.com";
    lnet = libnet_init(LIBNET_RAW4, NULL, errbuf);
    if ( lnet == NULL ) {
        NSLog(@"libnet_init() failed: %s", errbuf);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //IPv4
    addr = libnet_name2addr4(lnet, addr_str, LIBNET_RESOLVE);
    NSLog(@"%s",libnet_addr2name4(addr, LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE));
    //IPv6
    addr6 = libnet_name2addr6(lnet, addr_str, LIBNET_RESOLVE);
    libnet_addr2name6_r(addr6, LIBNET_DONT_RESOLVE, ipv6addr,
                        sizeof(ipv6addr));
    NSLog(@"%s",ipv6addr);
    libnet_destroy(lnet);

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Can anyone please explain the error to me in detail, and how to rectify it? Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I use Xcode 5.0.1 on Mavericks (v10.9.4)

UPD. I'v rebuild libnet for i386 arch from source and i'v got only one error:

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/usr/local/lib/libnet.dylib' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think there's a problem with compile libnet from source for iOS. How do it correctly?

Comment: For which device you're running this application, please select the device

Comment: Divice is "iPhone Retina (4-inch) simulator.

Comment: you might have defined architectures as `i386` in build settings and which I think is for mac not iOS devices

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105131/linking-against-dylib-built-for-macosx-file-usr-lib-libsystem-b-dylib-for-arc/19727843#19727843

Comment: If you have solved your problem then you can provide your answer for your question and accept as an answer so the the future audience will be benefited with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get libnet 1.1.7](https://github.com/sam-github/libnet)

Open a terminal window and go to libnet folder, next we need to compile libnet for iOS7 emulator:

```
export CC=clang
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0"
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Begin by selecting the project in Xcode. Select Target and then select Build Settings. Scroll down in the Build Settings until you get to the Linking section. Under the Other Linker Flags option, add -lnet. Now scroll down until you reach the Search Paths section and add /usr/local/lib to Library Search Paths. Finally, add /usr/local/include to the header's search path.

Comment: I tried to build.
Error:
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `libnet*.3', needed by `all-am'.  Stop.